# Unable to connect Firebase to android app | This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I know this question is already asked many times. But I have done the following things still I am getting an error **"This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console"**:

1. Added sha1 and sha256 from android studio signingReport build and also from play console dashboard
2. I am using a physical device to test
3. I have tried the inbuilt firebase tool of android studio to connect to firebase.
4. Test number also not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error when I was using Phone number authentication. Make sure you complete `Android Device Check API` requirements. This will enable your devices to be recognized.
use https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=capital-insider&folder=&organizationId=https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=capital-insider&folder=&organizationId=

and make sure you have added your app.

Comment: I have enabled it for the firebase project..But error not fixed. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: can you please send the stack trace ?

Comment: also make sure you have added the credentials , if you have not , go under manage and make sure you add the api key for android.

Comment: yeah I have to add OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
credential thanks..dont know why it is not auto created..but I don't think Android Device Check API required

Comment: it is ok now ? if it is do well to post your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230194/discussion-between-sum20156-and-ebs237).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

1. Go to google console
2. Select your project
3. APIs & Services -> Credentials
4. Make sure your app package name is registered with any OAth client ids
5. If not change it accordingly.
6. If you have the app in the store. Copy the sha1 key from the play console dashboard and change sha1 also.

[image]