# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I changed my app package name since it was "example" was rejected on the play store during upload but after  I changed it's unable to connect to firebase and I can no longer access the data there, I have also changed the package name on the manifest, build. Gradle and also the JSON file level but still, the app is giving back this error.

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below mentioned steps to resolve this issue :

1. Add android app in firebase console with your new package name and delete the old one .
2. Go to project settings in firebase console, add SHA1 and SHA-256 key there . For more info about debug and release keys check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780360/9942608)
3. Now download google-services.json and add into your project in android studio.
4. check applicationId in your build.gradle(:app)it should be the new one.
5. Clean and rebuild your project.
6. Test your app on real device .

Comment: I tried everything you said plus I had tried it before BUT the app still is not authorised what might be the issue here?