# firebase Authtentication isn't working on App's apk even it's working on debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, apk

i have been working on Flutter and using Firebase Authtentication. while i was coding my app i could log in with 3 ways: Phone Authentication, Google sign in and E-mail Authentication. on my app's apk i cant log in with Phone Authentication. after i got this error i tried on debug mode again and Phone Auth is still working. i cant get this issue. i did controlled SHA-1 and SHA-256 finger prints and both of them is correct. o apk i am getting this error:

```
[firebase_auth/app-not-authrized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authtentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in Firebase Console. [A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase Console. Please make sure that this application's packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console.]
```

i am sure that SHA-256 is registered and correct. what is the reason of this error?

***April 15th UPDATE:***

i deleted SHA1, SH256 keys and then get and save them again to Firebase Console. download the new google-services.json file and replace the old one but Authentication is not still working on apk even goes on working on debug mode on my real device. sign in with Email is working on apk and debug but Google SignIN and Phone auth is not. i am getting

```
PlatfomrException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10: ,null, null)
```

error if i try Sign in with Google and phone auth error continue the same here is my apk build output maybe it will help for solution:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease] in project C:\ornekler\sby_cpal_demo\android


> Configure project :app
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
> Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildRelease
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild
> Task :cloud_firestore:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :cloud_firestore:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_core:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_core:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :file_picker:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :file_picker:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :file_picker:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_core:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :cloud_firestore:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_auth:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_auth:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_auth:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_messaging:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_messaging:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_storage:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_storage:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_sms:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_sms:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_storage:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :url_launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_sms:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_sign_in:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_sign_in:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_messaging:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :image_picker:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :image_picker:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :image_picker:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_sign_in:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :cloud_firestore:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :file_picker:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_auth:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_core:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_messaging:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_storage:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_sms:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_sign_in:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :image_picker:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :url_launcher:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:cleanMergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :cloud_firestore:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :cloud_firestore:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :cloud_firestore:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :cloud_firestore:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :file_picker:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :file_picker:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :file_picker:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :file_picker:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_auth:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_auth:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_auth:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_auth:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_core:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_core:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_core:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_core:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_messaging:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_messaging:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_messaging:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_messaging:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_storage:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_storage:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :firebase_storage:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :firebase_storage:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_sms:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_sms:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_sms:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_sms:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_user_agent:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_user_agent:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :flutter_user_agent:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :flutter_user_agent:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :google_sign_in:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :google_sign_in:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :google_sign_in:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :image_picker:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :image_picker:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :image_picker:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :image_picker:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :url_launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :url_launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :url_launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :url_launcher:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
> Task :cloud_firestore:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :cloud_firestore:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :cloud_firestore:generateReleaseResources
> Task :cloud_firestore:packageReleaseResources
> Task :file_picker:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :file_picker:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :file_picker:generateReleaseResources
> Task :file_picker:packageReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_auth:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :firebase_auth:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_auth:generateReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_auth:packageReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_core:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :firebase_core:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_core:generateReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_core:packageReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_messaging:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :firebase_storage:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :firebase_messaging:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_messaging:generateReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_messaging:packageReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_storage:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_storage:generateReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_storage:packageReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:packageReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_sms:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :flutter_sms:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_sms:generateReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_sms:packageReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_user_agent:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :flutter_user_agent:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:generateReleaseResources
> Task :flutter_user_agent:packageReleaseResources
> Task :google_sign_in:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :google_sign_in:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_sign_in:generateReleaseResources
> Task :google_sign_in:packageReleaseResources
> Task :image_picker:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :image_picker:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :image_picker:generateReleaseResources
> Task :image_picker:packageReleaseResources
> Task :url_launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :url_launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :url_launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :url_launcher:packageReleaseResources
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :cloud_firestore:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :cloud_firestore:processReleaseManifest
> Task :file_picker:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :file_picker:processReleaseManifest
> Task :firebase_auth:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :firebase_auth:processReleaseManifest
> Task :firebase_core:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :firebase_messaging:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :firebase_storage:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :flutter_sms:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :firebase_core:processReleaseManifest
> Task :flutter_user_agent:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:processReleaseManifest
> Task :google_sign_in:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :firebase_messaging:processReleaseManifest
> Task :image_picker:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :url_launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :google_sign_in:processReleaseManifest
> Task :url_launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :flutter_sms:processReleaseManifest
> Task :flutter_user_agent:processReleaseManifest
> Task :firebase_storage:processReleaseManifest
> Task :image_picker:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :cloud_firestore:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :firebase_core:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :file_picker:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :firebase_auth:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :firebase_storage:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :firebase_messaging:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :flutter_sms:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :flutter_user_agent:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :url_launcher:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :firebase_core:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :file_picker:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :flutter_user_agent:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :firebase_auth:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :cloud_firestore:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :url_launcher:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :google_sign_in:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :firebase_messaging:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :firebase_storage:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :flutter_sms:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :image_picker:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :cloud_firestore:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :image_picker:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :google_sign_in:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :firebase_core:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :file_picker:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :firebase_auth:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :firebase_messaging:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :firebase_storage:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :flutter_sms:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :flutter_user_agent:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :url_launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :google_sign_in:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :image_picker:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :cloud_firestore:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :file_picker:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_auth:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_core:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_messaging:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_storage:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_sms:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_sign_in:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :image_picker:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :url_launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :url_launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :flutter_user_agent:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :flutter_user_agent:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_user_agent-1.2.2\android\src\main\java\io\jojodev\flutter\flutteruseragent\FlutterUserAgentPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :google_sign_in:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :google_sign_in:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.5.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :firebase_core:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :firebase_core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :flutter_user_agent:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :url_launcher:bundleLibCompileRelease

> Task :flutter_sms:compileReleaseKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.3, which is older than the API version 1.4. Consider using the runtime of version 1.4, or pass '-api-version 1.3' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.3. You can also pass '-language-version 1.3' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: C:\Users\omerkalfa\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\992306bf712cadc30b69c9f705670a64\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\Users\omerkalfa\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b7e5a140d96cd6c9ef247f728639e073\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\Users\omerkalfa\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eacb3212e6bcd2ffb5bee135749f60a3\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-2.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_sms\FlutterSmsPlugin.kt: (8, 48): 'Registrar' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-2.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_sms\FlutterSmsPlugin.kt: (16, 35): 'Registrar' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-2.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_sms\FlutterSmsPlugin.kt: (24, 33): 'Registrar' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sms-2.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_sms\FlutterSmsPlugin.kt: (67, 23): Parameter 'result' is never used

> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :google_sign_in:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :flutter_sms:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :flutter_sms:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :firebase_core:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :flutter_sms:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :file_picker:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :file_picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.1.7\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :firebase_storage:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :firebase_storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-5.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning

> Task :file_picker:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :cloud_firestore:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :cloud_firestore:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.14.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :firebase_auth:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :firebase_auth:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.18.4+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :cloud_firestore:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :firebase_storage:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :firebase_messaging:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :firebase_auth:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :image_picker:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :image_picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :firebase_messaging:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :image_picker:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileReleaseSources
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :firebase_core:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_core:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_auth:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_auth:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :cloud_firestore:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :cloud_firestore:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :url_launcher:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_messaging:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_messaging:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :image_picker:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :image_picker:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_sms:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :flutter_sms:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_storage:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :firebase_storage:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :google_sign_in:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :file_picker:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :file_picker:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :cloud_firestore:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :file_picker:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_auth:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_core:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_messaging:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_storage:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :file_picker:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_sms:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :firebase_messaging:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :flutter_user_agent:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :google_sign_in:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_sms:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :image_picker:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :flutter_user_agent:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :url_launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :google_sign_in:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :cloud_firestore:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :firebase_storage:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :cloud_firestore:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :firebase_auth:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :firebase_core:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :firebase_core:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :url_launcher:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :file_picker:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :flutter_sms:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :flutter_user_agent:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :firebase_messaging:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :firebase_storage:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :image_picker:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :google_sign_in:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :firebase_auth:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :image_picker:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :url_launcher:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :cloud_firestore:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :file_picker:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :cloud_firestore:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :cloud_firestore:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :cloud_firestore:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :firebase_auth:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :file_picker:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :file_picker:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :file_picker:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :firebase_core:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :firebase_messaging:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :firebase_core:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :firebase_core:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :firebase_core:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :firebase_storage:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :firebase_auth:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :firebase_auth:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :firebase_auth:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :flutter_sms:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :flutter_user_agent:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :flutter_sms:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :flutter_sms:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :flutter_sms:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :flutter_user_agent:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :flutter_user_agent:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :flutter_user_agent:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :image_picker:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :google_sign_in:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :google_sign_in:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :google_sign_in:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :url_launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :image_picker:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :image_picker:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :image_picker:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease
> Task :firebase_messaging:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :firebase_messaging:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :firebase_messaging:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :url_launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :url_launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :url_launcher:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :firebase_storage:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :firebase_storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :firebase_storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource

> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}

> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:shrinkReleaseRes

> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libapp.so, libapp.so, libapp.so, libflutter.so, libflutter.so, libflutter.so.

> Task :app:packageRelease
> Task :app:assembleRelease

BU�LD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 38s
298 actionable tasks: 259 executed, 39 up-to-date
```

at the bottom i got these warnings:

```
> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}

> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:shrinkReleaseRes

> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libapp.so, libapp.so, libapp.so, libflutter.so, libflutter.so, libflutter.so.
```

***APRIL 19TH UPDATE***

my problem still continues. can that be about developer account? i get some warnings Google Cloud and Platforms APIs and SERVICES project page. i am adding some screenshots of my projects page. i am really need help about this one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

i hope there is someone who help me here.

Comment: restrict you API key to android if your app is only working on android  and then check again your phone - auth .

Comment: I am still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear and specific, it cannot be anything else. Double check the google services json used for the APK build, and if you built a release or debug APK, You need to add both SHA keys, 256 and SHA1, for debug and for release.

Comment: i have just deleted both SHA keys and get and save them again to Firebase project settings but same result. what must i do? Auth working on debug mode but isnt working on apk. in addition i just built it' s apk not appBundle.

Comment: download the new google-services.json, and replace the one in the project, flutter clean, then build your apk again. Make sure you are building the app with the same name, for example if you have 2 apps in your project, make sure you are building the one with the corresponding `com.example.app`

Comment: i did that but not working. Email Authentication is woking but phone and Gmail Authentication not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the sign-in method phone in the authentication.
2. Add debug and release SHA-1 and SHA256 in the firebase settings.
3. Download google-services.json and add it to the project. Search your package name in the json file it should be there, if it's not it means you are adding wrong google-services.json file .
4. Run the app on the device(real device not emulator)

For more info check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780360/9942608)

Comment: i did that but not working on apk. Email Authentication is woking but phone and Gmail Authentication not even all of them is working on my real device on debug mode.

Comment: make sure it should be the same machine from where you are creating apk and from from where you added SHA -1 and SHA256 credentials . if you are using 2 laptops , make sure SHA-1 and SHA256 of both laptops/machines should be in firebase console .